# Node.js run a java program?

Tags: node.js

I have a simple nodejs server up and running. I am running into trouble when I try to spawn a child process. the jar file I am trying to access, is in the same directory as the node script. It takes in a command line argument that I am trying to pass in and it outputs data to the command line, which I am trying to pipe into the var child.

```
var child = require('child_process').spawn('java -jar done.jar',['argument to pass in']);

child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
});

child.stderr.on("data", function (data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

This produces the following error message:

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: spawn java -jar done.jar ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1046:32)
    at child_process.js:1137:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `spawn('java',[-jar', 'done.jar', 'etc...'])`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're executing `java`.  `-jar` and `done.jar` are arguments to pass.

```
var child = require('child_process').spawn(
  'java', ['-jar', 'done.jar', 'argument to pass in']
);
```

You will also need to specify the full path to `java`, or make sure that java is specified in the OS path.

Comment: Thanks Brad, that did it! For anyone who has the same problem I didn't need to specify the full path to java.

Comment: Worked for me too! However , i had to mention the full path of the jar file.