# Can a Node.js Application run and later invoke methods on a class of Springboot executable jar?

Tags: java, node.js, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, executable-jar

After thoroughly searching for any existing post for my issue, I ended up finding nothing helpful and hence asking my very first issue on stackoverflow :

**Problem Statement:**

I have an existing Node.js Application, and my requirement is to build a utility application using Springboot such that the Node.js Application can run the Springboot Application as an executable jar while startup and later is able to invoke methods of existing classes in the running Springboot Application Context.

**Note:**

The Springboot Application needs to initialise multiple beans and setup database handling using Spring Data JPA on startup.

Any thoughts are welcome!!

**Edit:**

I have tested the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242529/node-js-run-a-java-program), but it works only if the concerned jar is core java application. It doesn't work in case of Springboot application jar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js run a java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242529/node-js-run-a-java-program)

Comment: I already read this, but I have concerns about whether the same be applicable when the java application is a Springboot jar? Again, if possible, then my next concern is what will be the design of such Springboot Application